# If you append 2 pandas dataframes and assign to a variable, will it take space in memory?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management

If you append 2 pandas dataframes and assign to a variable, will it take space in memory?

For instance, if I have `df_1` which weights 500MB and `df2` also weighting 500MB,

after running this code below:

```
df_append = df_1.append(df_2, ignore_index = True)
```

Will my memory usage be 2000MB (500 + 500 + 1000), or will it be 1000MB?

Is this all about method we're using, `concat`, `append` and `merge`?

Comment: It'll use more memories, as all the operations you have mentioned are immutable and pandas returns a new dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `df_1` and `df2` both use 500MB of memory, then `df_append = df_1.append(df_2, ignore_index = True)` will build a new dataframe which will use more or less 1000 new MB, for a 2000MB total.

But beware, if a dataframe can be serialized into a 500MB file (for example in cdv format), it is likely to use far more memory...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask if there's another way of appending 2 dataframes, without using memory? Some kind of pointers or something similar

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you assign a var with the use of 1MB memory and the second var with the use of 1MB if you combine both ones and form a new var, then the new var take 2MB memory. Same as here. It will take approximately 1000MB, approximately huh... Don't think exactly. Because your df_1 could be used 500.000245(not exactly 500) and df_2 could be used 500.000something...(not exactly 500).

I hope you understand.